# flink + Kafka + JSON

Tags: java, json, maven, intellij-idea, apache-flink

I'm trying to test a Flink program to read a JSON data that came from Kafka using this JSONKeyValueDeserializationSchema class. However my Intellij is not finding this class. I suspect that some Maven dependency is missing or I'm using the wrong ones.

My pom.xml

```
    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
        <artifactId>flink-java_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>0.10.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
        <artifactId>flink-streaming-java_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
        <artifactId>flink-clients_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
        <artifactId>flink-connector-kafka-0.9_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

The image bellow shows my Intellij complaining.

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the same Flink version across all your dependencies.
Using this dependency section should fix the problems

```
<dependencies>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
    <artifactId>flink-java</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
    <artifactId>flink-streaming-java_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
    <artifactId>flink-clients_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
    <artifactId>flink-connector-kafka-0.9_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Comment: Hi Metzger, the first dependency that you suggested is not being resolved by Maven `<artifactId>flink-java_2.11</artifactId><version>1.1.1</version>` but looking at Maven repository I found this one that works `<artifactId>flink-java_2.11</artifactId><version>0.10.2</version>`  [link](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.flink/flink-java_2.11/0.10.2). However I'm not confident about this version changing. What do you think?

Comment: The Flink java dependency should be  
    `<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
    <artifactId>flink-java</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>`